# AngularJS route not resolved on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I try to implement a AngularJS router into my application.
So I have define one route (in `angular.module('MyModule').config()`) :

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:stepId?', {
          templateUrl: EditorApp.webDir + 'bundles/innovapath/angularjs/Step/Partial/step-form.html',
          controller: 'StepFormCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'stepFormCtrl',
          resolve: {
              step: [
                  '$route',
                  'PathService',
                  function($route, PathService) {
                      var step = null;

                      // Retrieve the step from route ID
                      if ($route.current.params && $route.current.params.stepId) {
                          step = PathService.getStep($route.current.params.stepId);
                      }

                      return step;
                  }
              ],
              inheritedResources: [
                  '$route',
                  'PathService',
                  function($route, PathService) {
                      var inherited = [];

                      var step = PathService.getStep($route.current.params.stepId);
                      if (angular.isDefined(step) && angular.isObject(step)) {
                          var path = PathService.getPath();

                          // Grab inherited resources
                          inherited = PathService.getStepInheritedResources(path.steps, step);
                      }

                      return inherited;
                  }
              ]
          }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/:stepId?'
    });
```

I'm also listening `$routeChangeStart` event, but it's not fired when my page is loaded.

I can't figure out why the route is not resolved. Moreover, when I refresh the page with `F5`, I got the same problem.

When I use internal link in my application the route resolution works perfectly.

Any idea ?

Comment: So when you click a link, the route works correctly, but if you refresh the page, or manually type the url hash, angular borks and doesn't load the route, correct?

My guess is that one of those services you're calling is depending on an object that is destroyed on page refresh and/or not set when you manually navigate to the page, however I can't see 'PathService' so I'm not sure what's happening in there.

Comment: Yes, that's it. No error, the controller is just not rendered and no event is fired.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but possibly $routeChangeStart only fires on subsequent route changes, and not on page load. Anyhow, if it's loading your controller, shouldn't you be able to move the logic of pulling whatever info you need out of the path into that controller rather than trying to handle it in the router?

Essentially if it's loading the correct controller and template, I'm not sure what isn't "resolving". I know $routeChangeStart doesn't fire, but what logic do you have that's dependent upon that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it.

Before the directive `ng-view` is processed I have lots of other parents directives which needs to be initialized, so it defer calculation of the route, which miss the `$locationChange` event.

Solution is to force route calculation with :

```
$route.reload();
```